# MySQL Workbench - how to display relationships?

Tags: mysql-workbench

How do I make Workbench display the connecting lines between tables when I define relationships?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you edit a table in an EER model, you will have a tab named `Foreign Keys` that allows you to define well... the foreign keys. These foreign keys will be visible in the diagram.

You can change the settings for the displayed relationship by double clicking on the line that connects the tables.

Comment: Sergio, I have defined the FKs properly. However, I only see the lines when I hover over it. I see the crow feet, but it's not clearly visible. I think it might be a display setting problem?

Comment: Most likely. I can clearly see the lines without hovering on them.

Answer (score 14):

You need to open reverse engineer: `Database->Reverse engineer CTRL+R`

Complete the wizard. It ask about the database to connect and other simple questions.

Just click `Next`.

After wizard completion the `MySQL Model` tab will be opened. **Click there `ERR Diagram` icon**

Answer (score 13):

I had an issue generated a PNG with the relationship lines.

Environment

- WorkBench version 8.0
- MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 with **Dark Theme**

Solution:

Disable dark theme and regenerate the diagram then export the PNG.

Comment: I had to change the relationship notation to anything other than cows foot from Model > Relationship Notation.

Comment: @RobinCSamuel, thank you for your comment. I had to change Relationship notation to display relationships

Comment: Dark mode was the culprit! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[image: You need to check draw line box]

You need to check draw line box.

Comment: relationships are still not autogenerated.

Comment: Same here, I do not get connecting lines.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench has three options for relationship visibility settings:

- Fully Visible
- Draw Split
- Hide

It sounds like you need to switch from Draw Split to Fully Visible. Double click on the endpoint, such as the crows feet. On the Relationship tab of the edit window you will is the Visibility settings.